why does python autocomplete jedi give this message in pulsar? "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named imp"
I am using pulsar editor and I am new to programming itself. I recently installed autocomplete-jedi and whenever I type something this keeps popping up:

autocomplete-python-jedi traceback output:
import imp
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named imp

this is what I see in the editor
I suppose as jedi analyzes local python files, I might have a module that imports 'imp' but I never used imp module. I have no clue what is happening. How to get rid of this message.

Jedi itself is raising that error, before it even starts analyzing your code. But why it's happening, IDK.
